# What is the error in the following factorial find C program?

Tags: c

My logic is entered `num` store into `temp` variable and find factorial using `temp = temp * (num - i)` inside `while` until `num` is greater than `0` and initially `i = 1` , but I get problem that my loop goes in to infinite loop how to solve this problem ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num, temp, i;

    printf("Enter a Num who's factorial is need to be find : ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("num = %d\n", num);
    temp = num;
    printf("temp =  %d\n", temp);
    i = 1;
    while (num > 0) {
        temp = temp * (num - i);
        i++;
        printf(" i = %d\n ", i);
    }
    printf("fact = %d \n ", temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(num > 0)` and where are you updating `num`?

Comment: Learn to use the *debugger.* If you single-step though the program and inspect the variables, the problem becomes apparent immediately.

Comment: Note that `int` can usually only store values up to 12! and even 64-bit unsigned integers can only work up to 20!

Comment: You could also use a `for` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you  are checking `num > 0` but never updating value of num `inside` the loop

Update it to check `num - i > 0` or `num > i`

```
while(num - i > 0)
{
    temp = temp * (num-i);
    i++;
    printf(" i = %d\n ",i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(num > 0)
    {
```

`num` is never updated inside the loop, so `num` will always be `> 0`.What you want is

```
while((num-i) > 0)
```

`i` is updated in every run of the loop, so eventually `num-i` will become `0` and the loop will terminate.

Answer (score 0):

`while(num>0)` was not updated. So You can use `while((num-i)>0)` for update loop.Try below C code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int num,temp,i;

printf("Enter a Num who's factorial is need to be find : ");
scanf("%d",&num);
printf("num = %d\n",num);
temp = num;
printf("temp =  %d\n",temp);
i=1;
while((num - i) > 0){
  temp = temp * (num-i);
  i++;
 printf(" i = %d\n ",i);
}
 printf("fact = %d \n ",temp);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't require an extra variable `i`. It is important that you should take care the time and space complexity of a program.

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main()
{
    int num,temp;    
    printf("Enter a Num who's factorial is need to be find : ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("num = %d\n",num);
    temp = 1;
    while(num > 0)
    {
        printf(" num= %d\n ",num);
        temp = temp * num;
        num--;
    }
    printf("fact = %d \n ",temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: /*C program to convert temp in faranheite into celcius*/

#include <stdio.h>
float far_cel(int);
int main()
{
 int Up,Lw,Step;
 float Res;
 Up = 300;
 Lw = 0;
 Res=0;
 for(Step=0;Step<=Up;Step=Step+20)
 {
  Res = far_cel(Step);
  printf("Res = %3.1f\n",Res);
 }
 return 0;
}
float far_cel(int Temp)
{
 int F;
 float C;
 F= Temp;
 C = (((float)(5/9)) * (F-32));
 return C;
} Hey Ashish can you help me to find error in the above program ?

Comment: @mulesandip3 try this: `C = (5.0/9) * (F-32);` in `far_cel` function.

Answer (score 0):

You never update `num` inside the body of the `while (num > 0)` loop, hence an infinite loop.

You should use a simpler method: a classic `for` loop with an index `i` incrementing from `1` to `n` inclusive.  This way you do not modify the value of `num` and can use it for the final output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num, res, i;

    printf("Enter a number whose factorial to compute: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &num) == 1) {
        res = 1;
        for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            res = res * i;
        }
        printf("%d! = %d\n", num, res);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- the initial value of `i` could be changed to `2`.
- factorials grow very quickly: this program will only handle numbers from `0` to `12`.  Changing the type of `res` to `unsigned long long` will handle up to `20`.